# How to refer on installing OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I compiled the code "learning" as follows and tried to include openCV using C++, but I got the following error message: I am using VScode on Mac os.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

Mat loadImage(const std::string& imagePath) {
    Mat image = imread(imagePath, IMREAD_COLOR);
    if (image.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load image: " << imagePath << std::endl;
        return Mat();
    }
    return image;
}

int main() {
    std::string imagePath = "sample.jpg";
    Mat image = loadImage(imagePath);
    if (!image.empty()) {
        imshow("Image", image);
        waitKey(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
g++-11 -std=c++14 -O3 -fopenmp -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.9.0_2/include/opencv4/ learning.cpp -o exe.learning
```

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "__ZN2cv3MatC1EOS0_", referenced from:
      __Z9loadImageRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE in ccA36q5q.o
  "__ZN2cv3MatC1Ev", referenced from:
      __Z9loadImageRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE in ccA36q5q.o
  "__ZN2cv3MatD1Ev", referenced from:
      __Z9loadImageRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE in ccA36q5q.o
      _main in ccA36q5q.o
  "__ZN2cv6imreadERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEi", referenced from:
      __Z9loadImageRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE in ccA36q5q.o
  "__ZN2cv6imshowERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKNS_11_InputArrayE", referenced from:
      _main in ccA36q5q.o
  "__ZN2cv7waitKeyEi", referenced from:
      _main in ccA36q5q.o
  "__ZNK2cv3Mat5emptyEv", referenced from:
      __Z9loadImageRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE in ccA36q5q.o
      _main in ccA36q5q.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If anyone knows how to fix this, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with linking OpenCV. Try something like this: 
`g++-11 -std=c++14 -O3 -fopenmp -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.9.0_2/include/opencv4/ -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.9.0_2/lib learning.cpp -o exe.learning -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui`

Comment: Thanks.I tried your advice but following error still exists. Do you know how to solve it? Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "__ZN2cv6imreadERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEi", referenced from:
      __Z9loadImageRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE in ccbgOnLw.o
  "__ZN2cv6imshowERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKNS_11_InputArrayE", referenced from:
      _main in ccbgOnLw.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status